# Change css content with data-content - break line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have:
HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" data-content="Loading..."></div>
```

CSS:

```
#mydiv:after{
   content: attr(data-content);
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 1;
   position: absolute;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   width: 100%;
   white-space: pre;
}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
$('.ui-effects-transfers').attr('data-content',"Loading... \A Please wait...");
```

I have problem, when I set in CSS

```
content: "Loading... \A Please wait...";
```

then **\A** work as breake line. When I set this with **data-content** the breake new line not work.

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Newline? Don't you mean `"Loading... \n Please wait..."`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\n` instead of `\A`

```
$("#mydiv").attr("data-content","hello\nworld");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhCrG/)

Comment: Omg... This not work, becuse I change data-content with FireBug. When I change with JS this work :)